# Is there a way to use a typedef struct variable in a function...?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Is there a way to use a typedef struct variable in a function if I've declared it in the main without passing it as a parameter?

```
    typedef struct {
        /* .... */
    }a;
    int main(){
        a boo;
        char string[40];
        function(string);
    }

    void function(char string[]){

        /* can I use the boo struct here in the function? */

    }
```

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Please post some code.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes"

Comment: @Yunnosch Simple, the answer "Yes" is as clear as the question (before the update). And now the question has been clarified, the answer is still "Yes" in theory, but probably "No" for all practical purposes. Which is to say that the question is still unclear. As it currently stands, the question appears to be an [XY   problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: For the "no" team, proving is probably hard. But you could explain something about visibility, scope, etc. to support the "no". (I happen to know that you can do that better than I can, though I bet on "no", too.) The "Yes" team could reopen-vote and put code where the "Yes" is....

Comment: Its a answerable question after edit.

Comment: @OP Can additional code be added to `main` to allow the `struct` to be used in the function?

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your change of tactic. I respect that. And I think I can almost see where you are going with your "Yes." I am honestly interested. I guess your reopen vote would make the path to write an answer. And if it is a well explained or code-supported "Yes" I would be happy to honor it.

Comment: @melpomene Too much for a comment, true. But mentioning the keywords, with a touch of explanation and then some links would make a good answer. Even if it ends up side-by-side with a code supported "Yes", because I think that one will be a honest, strictly correct but probably (let's say) laterally-thinking based answer. The pair would probably together provide for some real understanding and insight.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've reopened the question (since the OP did in fact update it), and I eagerly await your answer.

Comment: @user3386109 There seems to be a misunderstanding. I did neither write "Yes" nor "no". Sorry, if I confused anybody. I thought there are two other users itching to answer and just being prevented by the restrictions imposed by comments.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes I think the question (after edit) is clear. No I cannot write a good helpful answer for my guess that the answer is "no, not cleanly". Yes, I believe that your idea of how to do it (at least what I guess your idea is, judging from your clarification question) is a strictly correct answer. Which probably might not satisfy OP, but still shed some honestly helpful light on the matter. And yes, I believe that at least one commenter can write a decent answer for "no". I think questions can be clear, even if I cannot answer them.

Comment: @Yunnosch Regarding your comment about cynicism.  No, it's a rhetorical tactic, designed to elicit a response from the OP. And if you hadn't thrown a wrench into the works, things would have gone differently. One thing's for sure, the OP has not responded to my comment asking about changes to `main`, so that was clearly just a waste of time.

Comment: @user3386109 My design for a comment to provoke OP into giving more information would be "With the given information, the answer to this question currently would be 'No.' Would you like to provide more information, so as to make a more detailed answer possible? You could for example show some code to demonstrate the situation in which you want to do this." But styles differ. I recognise the idea behind your comment now and respect it. Sorry for misunderstanding it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198016/discussion-on-question-by-user11917097-is-there-a-way-to-use-a-typedef-struct-va).

Answer (score 3):

As the code in the question is currently written, no, `function` cannot access the variable `boo`.

You would either need to pass a pointer to `boo` as a parameter to `function`:

```
int main( void )
{
  ...
  function( string, &boo );
  ...
}

void function( char *str, a *b )
{
  ...
}
```

or you would need to declare `boo` at file scope (outside the body of either `main` or `function`):

```
a boo;

int main( void )
{
  ...
  function( string );
  ...
}

void function( char *str )
{
  // do something with str and boo
}
```

or, have a global pointer that you set to point to `boo`:

```
a *ptr;

int main( void )
{
  ...
  ptr = &boo;
  ...
  function( string );
  ...
}

void function( char *str )
{
  // do something with str and *ptr
}
```

Otherwise, `boo` is not visible to `function`.

**EDIT**

As user3386109 points out, the `typedef` isn't relevant here - the answer is the same regardless of how `boo` is declared, or whether its declared using a `typedef` name or not.

Comment: @Yunnosch In other words, the answer is either "No" or "Yes", depending on what the question is. That's pretty much the definition of an unclear question.

Comment: @user3386109 And you chose to state that the answer to the text-book unclear question is "Yes.". Remember my first question to you was, why answer AND close-vote for unclear.

Comment: @user3386109: That's true of *all* yes/no questions.  In this case, the question's clear enough to answer "no, not as currently written".  I then demonstrated how to make the answer "yes".

Comment: Combine the two and it's a *boostr*.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int main(){
   a boo;
   char string[40];
   function(string);
}
```

structure variable `boo` is *declared locally in `main()` function and you don't want to pass it to `function()` as a argument & wish to access in `function()`, answer is* **No** because `boo` is local to `main()` function i.e its having scope within `main()` only i.e where it is declared.

Though there are other ways like, declare a global pointer of struct type like

```
a *accessPtr;
```

and make `accessPtr` to point to `boo` in `main()` function like

```
int main(void) {
     a boo = {}; /*proper initialization */
     accessPtr = &boo; /* accessPtr points to boo, if you update/access accessPtr in function() it will get updated here as well.
     /* some code */
}
```

and now you can access/update the `accessPtr` in `function()`.